# How would I go about deformation of a scalar-field in a voxel-based, isosurface generation implementation?

Tags: java, voxel

I have implemented a system for generating iso-surface terrain, based on a regular 3D grid of voxels defined by a Perlin noise scalar field. The noise is obtained via a continuous function, so it is seamless across voxels and "chunks", (groups of voxels).

The problem I have run into is what to do to accomplish deformable terrain with this system. I have a "picking" system in place, so that I can select a voxel. Through this, I have access to the voxel's data, and can modify the scalar field at that point.

So far, I have tried modifying the data points in the selected voxel, (for example increasing of decreasing the values), which successfully moves the generated polygons up or down according to Marching Cubes.

However, this creates a tear in the terrain, as the triangles are separated from the rest of the mesh above or below.

What I need is a way to affect the scalar field itself in a natural way, starting at a localized point, and radiating outward from it, blending in seamlessly.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Data points, why plural?  Use a kernel (mask) to affect the neighbours to a lesser extent.  And always remember to re-draw all affected sections - Marching Cubes creates a manifold surface - it can't tear.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Right now, I modify the scalar field by copying values selected in the deformation area to surrounding data points. Then everything affected is re-computed and re-drawn. This works, to an extent, and does not tear, but is not very efficient.

Comment: Sounds like you've already started using Kernels.  It's the technique from image processing of using an extended mask to apply the effect in varying amounts to both the selected point and some to all of its neighbours, varied by arrangement (left of shadows, cross, X, circle, or square blur, etc).     (A) the Marching Cubes algorithm natively takes as input 8 neighbouring grid points that surround the face -- why not attach your cubic voxel to one such point only (its origin) [a corner, not the centre].  Unless your voxel data structure is difficult to traverse that should be efficient.